# Azure Storage: Is it possible to have more than 250 storage accounts per subscription?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-table-storage

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account) for Azure storage accounts, at most 250 accounts can be created per subscription. Is there a way to request a higher limit through Azure support or is this a hard limit that they won't be able to adjust due to technical constraints?

Comment: Open a support ticket and ask for a higher limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood it's limit as per the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account#scale-targets-for-standard-storage-accounts).

It says: "Number of storage accounts **per region** per subscription xxx".

Note the limit is per region per subscription. So in a subscription, you can create at most 250 storage account in a region(like EAST US), but you can still create at most 250 storage account in another region(like CENTRAL US) in the same subscription.

You can also find the limits in azure portal -> your subscription -> Usage + quotas. The screenshot as below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please note the new feature in public preview by Azure Storage which helps solve this pain point ..
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-5kaccountlimit/

Azure Storage is announcing public preview of the ability to create an additional 5000 Azure Storage accounts per subscription per region. This is a 20 times increase from the current limit of 250 and helps you create several hundred or thousand storage accounts to address your storage needs within a single subscription, instead of creating additional subscriptions.

Learn more - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-storage-blog/public-preview-create-additional-5000-azure-storage-accounts/ba-p/3465466